# How to draw the spectrogram from data the stft?

Tags: java, draw, drawrect

I have calculated stft(short time fourier transform) data. That is the number of the form a+bi. how would these can be drawn the spectrogram of frequency vs time, what function in java can I use.

[image: https://www.clear.rice.edu/elec301/Projects00/project/alex_overlap.jpg]

how to draw up like. I need one solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Java SE libraries do not cover this sort of thing.  You need to:

- identify a 3rd-party Java library that provides scientific graphing,
- identify a non-Java application that you can run to generate an image that you can embed in your Java app's output; e.g. run it using `Runtime.exec(...)`, or
- figure out how to render the image using the Java 2D libraries; i.e. by painting the pixels ...

Approaches 1 and 2 require you to do some research (e.g. Google).  Approach 3 requires you to understand the Java 2D graphics libraries, and code the solution for yourself.